# How to define a member function outside class in python?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:

        a = int()
        b = float()
        c = np.array([0 for i in range 10])

        def Memberfunction():

            print("Hii")
```

Comment: For such code how can I define the member function outside the class? Thank you in advance

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I have defined the member function MemberFunction inside the class MyClass, how can I do it outside the class as we do it in C++, like 
class MyClass{ 
int MemberFunction();
}
int MyClass::MemberFunction(){
cout<<"HII";
}
How to write such code in python?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Just checking if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class test_class():
    def __init__(self, some_func):
        self.some_value = 2    
        setattr(type(self), some_func.__name__, some_func)

def my_requested_func(self):
    print(self.some_value)

class_instance = test_class(my_requested_func)
class_instance.my_requested_func()
```

This should work, but I dont see any reason for you wanting to do this.

Comment: Yes but defining the Memberfunction() outside the class MyClass

Comment: @PrateekSarangi Updated.

Comment: 'test_class' object has no attribute 'some_func', Error shown, please help me out.

Comment: @PrateekSarangi Fixed, put the wrong function name :X

Comment: Ok thank you very much